# Text get smaller when textbox is clicked (bootstrap 3 mobile)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using Bootstrap 3. And I am using my mobile for testing that specific form. Texts get smaller when I clicked textbox. What should I do so that texts will have fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any font-size is given for the text box in css just for mobile.